# How to accelerate MATLAB online?

Tags: matlab, cloud

I am using MATLAB to operate a project addressing 1GB `nifti` files and doing regression analysis on them.

It usually takes half an hour to run all the codes on my PC (MacBook Air 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3). I am trying to expedite this process as I have to adjust the parameter several times and each time it will take half an hour, which is too long.

I tried [MATLAB online](https://matlab.mathworks.com) today. However, it even takes longer than my PC and sometime sessions out before I could get a result.

Is there a way to expedite it? Thanks.

Comment: MATLAB online operates on a limited environment and is designed only for quick prototyping and learning the language.  It is not designed for heavy computation.  It would really help us if you could provide any code that minimally reproduces what you're currently experiencing so that we can help.  Vectorizing goes a long way and I highly suspect that there is code running that it outside of the regression that's slowing it down.  Also have a look at `profile` to actually profile your code to see where the slow parts are.

Comment: first check Run&Time and try to optimize your code rather than just increasing the computational resources =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using MATLAB online, you could try running MATLAB on Amazon Web Services (AWS):
https://github.com/mathworks-ref-arch/matlab-on-aws

When you launch the resources in AWS, you will be able to choose the EC2 instance type on which to run MATLAB on. The speed up you will see will depend on the instance type you choose. 
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

To work with your data, you could upload the data to Amazon's S3 and then download the data from within the AWS machine.

---

Note that since you are launching resources in AWS, **there will be a cost associated with this type of deployment**.

Comment: What? You have to pay to get stuff? The shame! :p

Comment: If you can afford MATLAB then using an AWS instance for a day or so is a drop in the bucket in your expenses :p

Comment: Thanks. I was intended to save some money at first so I used MATLAB online. Now I am running my code on AWS :-)